# OData Client for Objective-C library for iOS 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am doing iphone project, in that am using ODataProtocol, but i can't able to find the Odatagen library for iOS 6. I taken OData4ObjC Zip file, in that Frameworks are Upto iOS 4.3 libraries are there.. how can i use that Odata libraries in my app for iOS 6. Is it possible?? When you will update the latest version of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

They just uploaded de IOS 6 framework https://github.com/ElizabethDuncan/OData4ObjC, hope this helps you